# fetch request using Django rest framework doesn't return data

Tags: django, api

I've set up a Django app with a React/Redux frontend. I've set up a simple API using Django Rest Framework and have confirmed that with the Django development server running, a cURL request returns valid data from the mySQL database.

However when I use a fetch request in the web page, no data is returned to the JavaScript code.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
return fetch('/api/lists/', { headers, })
    .then(res => {
        console.log('res ', res);
});
```

And here's what's printed in the console when it runs:

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lists/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body
:
(...)
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
true
redirected
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
"basic"
url
:
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lists/"
__proto__
:
Response
```

Obviously not the same response!

I have selected the request the browser sends in the Network tab and chosen Copy > Copy as cURL:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/lists/' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --compressed
```

If I paste this into a terminal window and run it, I get a JSON response:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"My first list","description":"A list is useful","is_public":false}]
```

So I think everything's working on the server side and I must be doing something wrong in the client web page.

I am running the Django development server on port 8000 and here's what it logs when the request is made:

```
"GET /api/lists/ HTTP/1.1" 200 85
```

It logs the exact same output whether I sent the request from the client or using cURL.

So, I am puzzled. The server thinks it's receiving the same request. If I copy the browser's request as cURL and run it in a terminal, I get a valid JSON response. But the client isn't seeing JSON in the response.

Very grateful for any ideas!

Comment: Try `console.log(res.json())`

Comment: res.json() prints: Promise {<resolved>: Array(1)}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Array(1)
0
:
{id: 1, title: "My first list", description: "A list is useful", is_public: false}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Sergey Pugach for pointing me in the right direction. I needed to do an extra step to get the data from the response:

```
let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
return fetch('/api/lists/', { headers, })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        // do something with data
    });
```

Note that the form of the response will vary with the library you're using to send the request. For example Django Rest Framework requires different handling from Axios.

Answer (score 0):

The `(...)` in the body are clickable in the chrome console. Your body data is probably there.